# How to add checkbox in Ext.tree.Panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a Ext.tree.Panel with Ext.data.TreeStore as the store.

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            region: 'west', //for border layout
            border: false,
            useArrows: true,
            cls: 'my-cool-tree',
            width: 200,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            margins: '5 3 5 5'
        });
```

I want to add checkbox but i am not getting any property like checked in the doc. Please let me know how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I want to add the checkbox for the root folder of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh setting checked property is working.......due to the absence of image I was not able to see the checkbox....now it is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can create and subsequently append xtype: 'checkbox' nodes to your root node.